# Let $R$ be a finite ring, and $S$ its subring. Then $|S|$ divides $|R|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm supposed to answer if this statement is true or false. I am extremely confused... I don't even know where to start. Does anybody have any hints?

Comment: A subring is a subgroup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subrings may not form a group with respect to multiplication, but subrings ALWAYS by definition form a group with respect to addition. Hence this statement is a direct application of Lagrange's theorem. The cosets will be additive ones!

Answer (score 1):

Since a ring consists in an additive group with some extra structure, you can apply Lagrange's theorem for groups.